# Using JSON.parse() with date fields?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say you have the following object as a string:

```js
var timecard = {
  "name": "Joe",
  "time": "Sun Apr 26 2015 13:58:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
} 

// as string
var stringed = 'var timecard = {   "name": "Joe",   "time": "Sun Apr 26 2015 13:58:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }'
```

and you run JSON.parse(stringed) to parse it into the object. How would you go about having it convert the date into an actual Date object as opposed to a string?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the declaration and assignment of stringed should be JSON.stringify(timecard)

Answer (score 5):

The JSON data format doesn't have a date type, so you have to write the code to transform it into a Date object yourself.

You can pass [a `reviver` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Example:_Using_the_reviver_parameter) as the second argument to JSON.parse to do that.

```js
    function parseDate(k, v) {
      if (k === "time") {
        return new Date(v);
      }
      return v;
    }
    var json = '{   "name": "Joe",   "time": "Sun Apr 26 2015 13:58:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }';
    var data = JSON.parse(json, parseDate);
    console.log(data);
```

Comment: What if you do not have the time variable name available? ie. its a JS library for parsing objects

Comment: @JimMarcus — Then you have to use some other method to determine which fields you want to convert to dates. e.g. you could write a "Looks like a date" regular expression, or try to convert everything to dates and see what is converted successfully.